# CSS Media queries for Mobile & Large screen sizes

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, tablet

I have a Magento store for a client and need to have a certain ID/Class have the "zoom" size changed based on screen size:

[Tuga Sunwear - Gift Card](https://tugasunwear.com/gift-card)

The DIV ID is "giftcard-template-back" and you can find it by doing "inspect element" on the giftcard background image (text has separate classes), this is what I have so far, but it's not working:

```css
@media screen and (min-device-width: 0px) and (max-device-width: 479px) {
  #giftcard-template-back {
     zoom: 41%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-width: 959px) {
  #giftcard-template-back {
     zoom: 67%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 960px) {
  #giftcard-template-back {
     zoom: 98%;
  }
}
```

It works when I disable the 41% from the preceding DIV..but I can't figure out how to turn it off completely.

I'm not super great with mobile CSS so if this needs some dire cleanup, please let me know.

What I am trying to do is have the "zoom" set at shown percentages between 0px-479px, 480px-959px, and 960px +

I searched around a little bit but couldn't find anything exactly like this, the closest was [Media Queries - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile), so I appreciate the help I can get from you all!

** EDITS **

**I have applied the "#" to the class names and updated the CSS a little. The desktop 960px+ shows perfectly but when I resize my window, it still loads the 98% zoom. Does anyone have a suggestion?**

Comment: I am also noticing, my changes kind of take effect, but are being overwritten by <div> under "product_tabs_gallery_contents" which has no class :/ I am using the Gift Card extension from Magestore - I cannot provide the code since it was a paid extension.

Answer (score 1):

ID CSS selectors start with a `#` It should be `#giftcard-template-back`

```css
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 479px) {
  #giftcard-template-back {
     zoom: 41%;
  }
}    
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 959px) {
  #giftcard-template-back {
     zoom: 67%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 960px) {
  #giftcard-template-back {
     zoom: 98%;
  }
}
```